# Create image in browser from Image object

Tags: java, image, internet-explorer, applet, sandbox

In my Java applet, I have an `Image` object. Now I want to open a browser window from this program and show the image from this `Image` object in the browser.  The applet is sandboxed, so saving the image to the local file system is not an option.

How can I show the image in the browser?

---

In the *current* implementation:

- applet convert the image to base64 code then
- pass it to classic asp then this
- asp write this base64 code to server and
- pass the name of file and required information to c program, and then
- c program call a java program which is on server side then this
- java program read the base64 code and convert it to image
- then asp read this image and show in a browser

This process takes too much time to perform.

I just need to show the image created in applet, in a new popup which can be saved if the user wants.  Currently the users are running IE 7 but it may be of any version in our requirement.

Comment: You have to save the image data to a file and then open it in a browser using the url mapped with virtual path of the image

Comment: As this is applet so image can not be save to the file system because applet does not have permission to access the file system

Comment: If you make it a signed Applet, this can access the file system.

Comment: @Naved  While signing the code allows access to the local file system, this is one of those many things that we would want of a sand-boxed applet.  I often find myself jumping through hoops to offer features while avoiding signing an applet (after which what I'm attempting to offer would be simple).

Comment: I edited your question and added a slightly altered version of one of your comments *"Currently the users are running IE 7 but it may be of any version in our requirement."*  Is that correct?  The users can upgrade to IE 9?

Comment: No it is my development machine which contains IE7, different users may have different versions of IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never done it, but I expect something like this would work:

- Encode the image as [base 64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) in the applet.  Note that the J2SE has no inbuilt class/method for base 64 conversion.  You'll either need to code it, or add an API that can do it.
- Pass the encoded data to JavaScript.
- Use JavaScript to write (or alter the `src` of an existing) [`img` element in the page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML).

---

> ..internet explorer does not support this..

Taking (copy/pasting) the example from the 2<sup>nd</sup> link and wrapping it in some `body` & `html` elements, gives:

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot">
</body>
</html>
```

When that is opened in IE I see..

[image: Red dot in IE 8]

For more detail on support in IE, see [Data URI scheme: Disadvantages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Disadvantages), which mentions..

- ..
- Internet Explorer through version 7 (approximately 5% of web traffic as of September 2011), lacks support. However this can be overcome by serving browser specific content.[8]
- Internet Explorer 8 limits data URIs to a maximum length of 32 KB. (Internet Explorer 9 does not have this limitation)[4][3]
- ..

Comment: but internet explorer does not support this and I have to done it in internet explorer

Comment: but I try it, it is not opening in my internet explores it shows cross mark with written Red dot

Comment: Imagine for a moment that I am not sitting in front of your IE, and share with me the version number of that browser.

Comment: I just need to show the image created in applet, in a new popup which can be save if user want, in current implementation applet convert the image to base64 code then pass it to classic asp then this asp write this base64 code to server and pass the name of file and required information to c program, and then c program call a java program which is on server side then this java program read the base64 code and convert it to image then asp read this image and show in a browser, so this process takes much time to perform, currently I am using IE 7 but it may be of any version in our requirement